# Python setting values for keys in nested dictionaries when keys are the same

Tags: python, dictionary

Really simple situation but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I have a dictionary that contains a bunch of other dictionaries that I'm using to store configurations. Each nested dictionary is created from the same template, so the keys are the same. When trying to set a key in one of them, the same key across all the nested dictionaries gets updated with the value.

Here's an example of the kind of thing I'm doing.

```
my_dict = {
    "bar": {
        "baz": None,
        "qux": None
    },
    "foo": {
        "baz": None,
        "qux": None
    }
}

my_dict['foo']['baz'] = True
```

Then the dictionary looks like this, I don't understand why?
I'm sure I've done this kind of thing fine before as well which is why its confusing.

```
{
    "bar": {
        "baz": True,
        "qux": None
    },
    "foo": {
        "baz": True,
        "qux": None
    }
}
```

EDIT

The nested dictionaries are created using a template like this:

```
temp = {'baz': None,
        'qux': None}
 
my_dict['foo'] = temp
my_dict['bar'] = temp
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank You

Comment: can you post the code for how the dictionary was created? Or is that it. Running this on my machine does not produce the same output as the one you've provided

Comment: I've edited the question to show how I'm creaing them, as I'm not actually defining them with my_dict, that was kind of just to demo. This isn't how I'm using it in my code, but I am creating them in the same way so its still happening in both cases.

I think the penny has dropped, when I'm updating any of the nested dictionaries I guess I'm updating this reference dictionary. Any ideas how I'd go about this without encountering this problem?

Comment: I'd look at Ann's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `copy` method in order to copt a `dict` type without them being related to each others:

```
my_dict = {}

temp = {'baz': None,
        'qux': None}
 
my_dict['foo'] = temp.copy()
my_dict['bar'] = temp.copy()

print(my_dict)
my_dict['foo']['baz'] = True
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'bar': {'baz': None, 'qux': None},
 'foo': {'baz': None, 'qux': None}}

{'bar': {'baz': None, 'qux': None},
 'foo': {'baz': True, 'qux': None}}
```

*Note: You don't need to call `.copy()` twice in this case, because you're not using `temp` elsewhere in your code. So it changing it's content is fine as long as you have another dict that does use `.copy()`.*

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs because you're pointing `my_dict['foo']` and `my_dict['bar']` to the same object. So once that object is changed, the value for both will be changed.

On top of what Ann has, you could try using this since your dictionary is shallow:

```py
my_dict = {}

temp = {'baz': None,
        'qux': None}
 
my_dict['foo'] = dict(temp)
my_dict['bar'] = dict(temp)

print(my_dict)
my_dict['foo']['baz'] = True
print(my_dict)
```

`dict` creates a new dictionary object.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any advantage to either method? I may be using deeper nested dictionaries as I develop this code.